# awk to print all columns formatted

Tags: awk, pattern-matching

I want to format below un-formatted inputs. I would like to print all the fields if the second column begins with "2".

Actual file contains many columns. Is there any easiest way to print all columns instead of typing print `$2,$3,$4,$5,...$n`?

Input.csv

```
---------------------------
|Data statistics|Number of|
|-------------------------|
|Records passed |  750,517|
---------------------------
Transaction Data for Serial Numbers

No of Records :                                                      750517

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|Material Number|Serial Number From |Serial Number To   |Document Year|Delivery Document|Material Document|
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|200965         |18604165309338     |18604165309387     |2012         |6100202749       |AAA2778202       |
|201163         |10740000822407     |10740000822606     |2012         |6100202749       |AAA2778202       |
|201232         |18604177741067     |18604177741366     |2012         |6100202749       |AAA2778202       |
|201295         |18604221522337     |18604221523836     |2012         |6100202749       |AAA2778202       |
|201480         |18604113309952     |18604113310131     |2012         |6100202749       |AAA2778202       |
|201781         |18604199150436     |18604199150835     |2012         |6100202749       |AAA2778202       |
|201480         |6001400030046472   |6001400030046771   |2012         |6100202520       |AAA2777953       |
|202853         |6001700000180323   |6001700000180722   |2012         |6100202520       |AAA2777953       |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I am unsing below command :

```
awk ' BEGIN {FS ="|"; OFS = ","} { if ($2~"2") print $2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7 }' Input.txt
```

Desired Output:

```
200965         ,18604165309338     ,18604165309387     ,2012         ,6100202749       ,AAA2778202       
201163         ,10740000822407     ,10740000822606     ,2012         ,6100202749       ,AAA2778202       
201232         ,18604177741067     ,18604177741366     ,2012         ,6100202749       ,AAA2778202       
201295         ,18604221522337     ,18604221523836     ,2012         ,6100202749       ,AAA2778202       
201480         ,18604113309952     ,18604113310131     ,2012         ,6100202749       ,AAA2778202       
201781         ,18604199150436     ,18604199150835     ,2012         ,6100202749       ,AAA2778202       
201480         ,6001400030046472   ,6001400030046771   ,2012         ,6100202520       ,AAA2777953       
202853         ,6001700000180323   ,6001700000180722   ,2012         ,6100202520       ,AAA2777953
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ awk 'gsub(/\|/,",") && gsub(/^,|,$/,"") && /^2/' file
200965         ,18604165309338     ,18604165309387     ,2012         ,6100202749       ,AAA2778202
201163         ,10740000822407     ,10740000822606     ,2012         ,6100202749       ,AAA2778202
201232         ,18604177741067     ,18604177741366     ,2012         ,6100202749       ,AAA2778202
201295         ,18604221522337     ,18604221523836     ,2012         ,6100202749       ,AAA2778202
201480         ,18604113309952     ,18604113310131     ,2012         ,6100202749       ,AAA2778202
201781         ,18604199150436     ,18604199150835     ,2012         ,6100202749       ,AAA2778202
201480         ,6001400030046472   ,6001400030046771   ,2012         ,6100202520       ,AAA2777953
202853         ,6001700000180323   ,6001700000180722   ,2012         ,6100202520       ,AAA2777953
```

To address your comment below:

```
$ awk 'gsub(/\|/,",") && gsub(/^,|,$/,"") && $3~/^,600/' file
201480         ,6001400030046472   ,6001400030046771   ,2012         ,6100202520       ,AAA2777953
202853         ,6001700000180323   ,6001700000180722   ,2012         ,6100202520       ,AAA2777953

$ awk -F, 'gsub(/\|/,",") && gsub(/^,|,$/,"") && $3~/^600/' file
201480         ,6001400030046472   ,6001400030046771   ,2012         ,6100202520       ,AAA2777953
202853         ,6001700000180323   ,6001700000180722   ,2012         ,6100202520       ,AAA2777953
```

Comment: You're welcome. If you have another question, please put more thought into the example you create. In this case you SAID you only wanted lines that start with "2" but your input ONLY contained lines that start with "2" so there was nothing to test against to see if the potential solution satisfied that requirement. My first attempt produced the expected output you posted from the sample input you posted and it was @fedorqui who noticed that it didn't actually work as I was ignoring your "only lines that start with 2" requirement.

Comment: Ed Morton,when i tried to extract the line intems if $3 begins with 600 below command is not working, please suggest.. awk 'gsub(/\|/,",") && gsub(/^,|,$/,"") && $3~/^600/' Input.txt

Comment: @BBB what do you mean by `$3`? None of the fields in your input start with 600 or any other number, after the first 2 gsub()s they all start with `,`. THINK about what awk uses as the default field separator and you'll understand why. If you want it to use something different then you need to tell it that.

Comment: @EdMorton, looking to choose below line items from above input,**201480         ,6001400030046472   ,6001400030046771   ,2012         ,6100202520       ,AAA2777953       
202853         ,6001700000180323   ,6001700000180722   ,2012         ,6100202520       ,AAA2777953**

Comment: I can't tell exactly what that is in your comment. Is the script I posted earlier at the end of my answer not working for you?

Answer (score 2):

You can say:

```
$ awk -F"|" -v OFS="," '$2~/^2/ {NF--; $0=$0; print}' file
,200965         ,18604165309338     ,18604165309387     ,2012         ,6100202749       ,AAA2778202       
,201163         ,10740000822407     ,10740000822606     ,2012         ,6100202749       ,AAA2778202       
,201232         ,18604177741067     ,18604177741366     ,2012         ,6100202749       ,AAA2778202       
,201295         ,18604221522337     ,18604221523836     ,2012         ,6100202749       ,AAA2778202       
,201480         ,18604113309952     ,18604113310131     ,2012         ,6100202749       ,AAA2778202       
,201781         ,18604199150436     ,18604199150835     ,2012         ,6100202749       ,AAA2778202       
,201480         ,6001400030046472   ,6001400030046771   ,2012         ,6100202520       ,AAA2777953       
,202853         ,6001700000180323   ,6001700000180722   ,2012         ,6100202520       ,AAA2777953
```

Comment: You should mention that `NF--; $0=$0` will only work in some awks.

Answer (score 1):

This may help you

```
$ cat file
---------------------------
|Data statistics|Number of|
|-------------------------|
|Records passed |  750,517|
---------------------------
Transaction Data for Serial Numbers

No of Records :                                                      750517

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|Material Number|Serial Number From |Serial Number To   |Document Year|Delivery Document|Material Document|
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|200965         |18604165309338     |18604165309387     |2012         |6100202749       |AAA2778202       |
|201163         |10740000822407     |10740000822606     |2012         |6100202749       |AAA2778202       |
|201232         |18604177741067     |18604177741366     |2012         |6100202749       |AAA2778202       |
|201295         |18604221522337     |18604221523836     |2012         |6100202749       |AAA2778202       |
|201480         |18604113309952     |18604113310131     |2012         |6100202749       |AAA2778202       |
|201781         |18604199150436     |18604199150835     |2012         |6100202749       |AAA2778202       |
|201480         |6001400030046472   |6001400030046771   |2012         |6100202520       |AAA2777953       |
|202853         |6001700000180323   |6001700000180722   |2012         |6100202520       |AAA2777953       |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Output**

```
$ awk 's=$1~/^\|2/{gsub(/^\||\|$/,""); gsub(/\|/,",")}s' file
200965         ,18604165309338     ,18604165309387     ,2012         ,6100202749       ,AAA2778202       
201163         ,10740000822407     ,10740000822606     ,2012         ,6100202749       ,AAA2778202       
201232         ,18604177741067     ,18604177741366     ,2012         ,6100202749       ,AAA2778202       
201295         ,18604221522337     ,18604221523836     ,2012         ,6100202749       ,AAA2778202       
201480         ,18604113309952     ,18604113310131     ,2012         ,6100202749       ,AAA2778202       
201781         ,18604199150436     ,18604199150835     ,2012         ,6100202749       ,AAA2778202       
201480         ,6001400030046472   ,6001400030046771   ,2012         ,6100202520       ,AAA2777953       
202853         ,6001700000180323   ,6001700000180722   ,2012         ,6100202520       ,AAA2777953
```